# Adding a new RLMObject to an existing Realm - Schema and Migrations

Tags: ios, realm, realm-migration

### Overview

I have an existing Realm with about two dozen persisted models. That Realm's configuration and its corresponding schema-version is 1. Recently some new features were added to the application which required adding a new model to the Realm. Given that addition of the model, incrementing the schema-version to 2, since a new model was added seems, the logical thing to do since the schema changed by adding a new model. Yet it yields a crash.

### Expected Result

With a new model added to the Realm, I should increment the Realm configuration schema-version to 2, and have a handler for the migration. No properties were changed to any existing models. Everything should just work.

### Actual Results

With a new model added to the Realm, and incrementing the Realm configuration schema-version to 2, with a handler block for the migration, Realm crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Decrementing the Realm configuration schema-version back to 1 seems to fix the crash.

---

The documentation is clear about incrementing the schema-version, and migration block handler when changing a models properties. Though it is unclear about merely adding a new model and incrementing the schema-version.

Can anyone clarify and validate?

- Running Realm 0.96.3 (realm-cocoa)
- Xcode 7.3.1 (7D1014)

Comment: Firstly, Realm 0.96.3 is quite an old version. The most recent version is v1.0.2. Secondly, can you share the backtrace of the crash you're seeing? It likely contains information that will help understand why it's happening.

Comment: @bdash Thank you for responding so promptly. We are behind in versions for sure. Here is a recent [trace of a crash](https://gist.github.com/mteece/535afb512b3b7120c2fb2bc7da7cf3f4).

Comment: That crash looks to be the same as https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/3398, which is an apparent incompatibility between older versions of Realm and Xcode 7.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding new model classes to a Realm does not require a migration or a schema version bump; only making changes to an existing one.

If you can reproduce the crash with a recent version of Realm then a bug report on [the issue tracker](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues) would be very appreciated, but there's a good chance it's been fixed in the 7 months since 0.96.3 was released.